# __call and __callStatic not working properly or writing incorrectly

Tags: php, call, construct

```
<?php
    class Statics {

        private static $keyword;

        public static function __callStatic($name,$args){
            self::$keyword = "google";
        }
        public static function TellMe(){
            echo self::$keyword;
        }
    }

    Statics::TellMe();
```

This is a simple breakdown I tried using `__construct` but the way I write the code `Statics::TellMe();` I would need to write `new` for the `__construct` to work. And my private static variable `keyword` does not get written without it being called any ideas as to why this is not working??

[**IDE Not Working Example**](http://ideone.com/nw5jss)

```
    private static $pathname;
    public function __construct($dir = "")
    {
        set_include_path(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]));
        if($dir !== "") {
            $dir = "/".$dir;
        }
        self::$pathname = $dir.".htaccess"; 
        if( file_exists(self::$pathname) ) {
            self::$htaccess = file_get_contents($dir.".htaccess",true);
            self::$htaccess_array = explode("\n",self::$htaccess);
        }
    }
```

The `self::$patname` is not getting assigned because I am not doing `$key = new Key();` so I need a way to do it if I just do `Key::get()` or anything like that.

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong : __callStatic should be declared as public static __callStatic

Comment: ok lol I'll try that out thought it had to be a function too -_-

Comment: still not working -_- ugh such a pain in the rear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a misunderstanding in the way `__callStatic` is working.
The magic method `__callStatic` will act like a fallback method when a static method is unknow to the class.

```
class Statics {

    private static $keyword;

    public static function __callStatic($name,$args){
        return 'I am '.$name.' and I am called with the arguments : '.implode(','$args); 
    }
    public static function TellMe(){
        return 'I am TellMe';
    }
}

echo Statics::TellMe(); // print I am TellMe
echo Statics::TellThem(); // print I am TellThem and I am called with the arguments : 
echo Statics::TellEveryOne('I','love','them'); // print I am TellEveryOne and I am called with the arguments : I, love, them
```

So in your case what you could do is :

```
class Statics {

    private static $keyword;

    public static function __callStatic($name,$args){
        self::$keyword = "google";
        return self::$keyword;
    }
}

echo Statics::TellMe();
```

As per your edit :

```
class Statics{
    private static $pathname;
    private static $dir;

    public function getPathName($dir = "")
    // OR public function getPathName($dir = null) 
    {
        if($dir !== self::$dir || self::$pathname === ''){
        // OR if($dir !== null || self::$pathname === ''){ -> this way if you do getPathName() a second time, you don't have to pass the param $dir again
            self::$dir = $dir;
            set_include_path(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]));
            if($dir !== "") {
                $dir = "/".$dir;
            }
            self::$pathname = $dir.".htaccess"; 
            if( file_exists(self::$pathname) ) {
                self::$htaccess = file_get_contents($dir.".htaccess",true);
                self::$htaccess_array = explode("\n",self::$htaccess);
            }
        }
        return self::$pathname;
    }
}

echo Statics::getPathName('some');
```

Comment: This was just a generalized case, trying to get the `self::$keyword` to get created. I'll update with what my code actually looks like for the `__construct` method

Comment: Yes but you cannot, in PHP construct a static class. Then you have to work around like in my edit or play with a `::init() static function first`

Comment: I'll see what I can do, may just have to initialise it. Thanks @b.enoit.be